# Is it possible to recreate the C++ header files needed to use a given .dll/.so/.dylib?

Tags: c++, dll, dylib, shared-libraries

Is it possible to recreate the C++ header files needed to use a given .dll/.so/.dylib?

If it is, how would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. There is a lot of information in header files (structure layouts, numeric constants, etc) that are not available in the dynamic library.

You *may* be able to recover some function parameter information if the library exports "decorated" C++ function names. However, even with that, you won't be able to get enough information to reconstruct a useful header file.

If the library exports undecorated names (with `extern "C"`), then you're pretty much out of luck. All you know at that point is the function names.

Answer (score 1):

That's called reverse engineering, and by itself is not an easy task, getting the function names and parameters is easy because of C++ name mangling, but recovering other data such as enumerations, constants and #defines used by the library can be a bit of a pain, because that data will be embedded into the assembly of the library.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Matias' answer, reverse engineering requires a few different topics of knowledge. For starters, at least basic assembly is a must. You'll need to learn more and more depending on the complexity of what you're doing but at least understand the basics of the language. The second thing is debugging. There are various tools to assist you, probably the most prominent on Windows is OllyDBG, on Linux I like EDB or Evan's Debugger. The last thing you'll need is a good disassembler such as IDA Pro (pricey but there's a free version I believe). There's plenty of books and online resources to learn about reverse engineering if you're really interested in it. Good luck!